# What is the right ExpectedConditions to wait for when waiting for text field using selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Currently whenever I want to wait to any web element (text field, dropdown etc) I use `elementToBeClickable`:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("someXpath")))
```

but I get some issue sometime with a certain text field web element, one that I need to type text in and get auto completion, sometime it stuck during automation and if I click on it the automation returns to work.......so weird.

I thought it might have something to do with the ExpectedConditions..?
Anyone ever had this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elementToBeClickable` would basically check if the element *is visible and enabled*.

> I thought it might have something to do with the ExpectedConditions..? Anyone ever had this issue?

I don't think the problems you are describing are related to the wait and expected conditions.

Also, not sure if it is related, but sometimes you need to *click a text field* before sending keys to it. And, sometimes you need to *move to an element*, click and then send keys to it.

Comment: thankssss , it really helped me to do this click before :)

Comment: Keep in mind that you can do a "native sendkeys" that types into a text field OR you can just directly set the value of the field using a JavascriptExecutor.   That would be one wait to avoid clicking in a text field before you type.